# I want to take data from database and compare with system time

Tags: android, sqlite, time

I want to take data from database and compare with system time.my android code for taking system time is

```
sTimeFirstPart= DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
```

this will hold the current system time and how can i compare this time to time in database table my db table is look like this

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names3 (_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY     AUTOINCREMENT, medicine VARCHAR, dose1 VARCHAR ,dose2 VARCHAR ,dose3 VARCHAR)");
```

dose1,dose2,dose3 are the time value stored in the database.

and i want to display  the next medicine at what time how can i  do this pls help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider storing the date as Millis since the epoch -- what `System.currentTimeMillis()`  returns.

Then add a column "theTime" as long to the table and store the next intake date there.

Here comparison using < and > is easy:

```
SELECT dose FROM names3 WHERE theTime < ?
```

and pass the current time as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Android dev, but comparing dates as strings is a bad idea on any platform. Why don't you use Date instead of String?
You can transform the Varchar to a Date like [this](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/19.html) and then compare it to the current time with [compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29).

Answer (score 0):

This example resolves that problem:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 
  start_date <= date('now','localtime') 
  AND end_date >= date('now','localtime')
```

[Look here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for other date functions in SQLite.

Comment: You don't have to add time column as long type, like in accepted answer.